# Running echo with flags in a Makefile under WSL

Tags: linux, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a `Makefile` from under WSL that contains the following lines:

```
debug: create_soft_links
@mkdir -p Debug64
@echo -e 'all: bld'                                             > Debug64/Makefile
@echo                                                          >> Debug64/Makefile
@echo -e '%.o: ../../%.c'                                      >> Debug64/Makefile
@echo -e '\tgcc -g $$(CFLAGS) $$(INCLUDE) $$< -o $$@'          >> Debug64/Makefile
```

Problem is that the resulting `Debug64/Makefile` file looks like this:

```
-e all: bld

-e %.o: ../../%.c
-e      gcc -O3 $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

A colleague just showed me on an actual Linux machine that the `make` command works correctly there, and the preceding `-e` flag is not printed in the generated `Debug64/Makefile`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The short answer is that there's no standardized set of arguments to the `echo` command defined by POSIX.  So any use of `-e`, `-n` or other common options are inherently non-portable.  `echo` should only ever be used to print very simple strings that should end with a newline.  Anything more complex than that should be using the `printf(1)` utility, not `echo`, as Basile mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead of `echo` the [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) command. So your last line would be

```
@printf "\tgcc -g %s %s $$< -o $$@\n" $$(CFLAGS) $$(INCLUDE)
```

BTW, if you generate your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) script, consider switching to [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). You might use [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) or [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) as such a generator.

Comment: Worked. And carrying out `$$(CFLAGS) $$(INCLUDE)` wasn't necessary, I didn't want those values parsed.